# how to create a php array like this?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(
    array(
    'A'=>0,
    'B'=>0,
    'C'=>0,
    'D'=>0,
    'E'=>0
    ),
    array(
    'A'=>1,
    'B'=>0,
    'C'=>0,
    'D'=>0,
    'E'=>0
    )
    .......
)
```

In this array, every A B C D E has both 0 and 1 condition. But I don't know how to create an array like this.

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065939/add-2-values-to-1-key-in-a-php-array

Comment: Array is already created. Solved!

Comment: show me full array you want...

Comment: what is the maximal number of nested arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming you are going to dynamically add the 0 and 1 values against your A,B,C,D,E in the arrays.

```
$count = 10; // This is the number of objects you want to add to your master array, which you can either keep static or compute dynamically.
$valueA = 0; // Similarly define all your values against A,B,C,D,E here.

$dynamicArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
   $dynamicArray[$i] = array("A"=>$valueA,"B"=>$valueB,"C"=>$valueC,"D"=>$valueD,"E"=>$valueE);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code . I had solved it: ```$k = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
for($i=0;$i<32; $i++) {
  $v = str_split(sprintf('%05b', $i));
  $a[] = array_combine($k, $v);
}
print_r($a);```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I think standard functions like [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill-keys.php), [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill.php) and [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php) might be of use.

Seriously, php.net is such a great site.